# Git's login form says login fail when typing all the credentials properly

Tags: git, forms, authentication, github

I am trying to push changes of my repositoy with `git push -u origin main` Then Git's login window pops up https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/github/images/011.png. I type all my
credentials properly, but it says wrong credentials. Then I try to type the **same** credentials
from command line, then it works.

Comment: What's the specific error message?

Comment: ```Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com':
``` ; Then I type the same credentials (from command line) and then it works

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar situation like you :(
When Git login popup appears, I close it with `esc` and type username and password in command line.
*(Because as you said, strangely, we can log in well only from `cmd`..)*

However, **there is a hassle of typing username and password every time**.
So if it is a frequently used repository, try below method.

1. Enter below code in cmd

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push https://github.com/username/repositoy name.git
  (ex. git push https://github.com/devncore/the-easiest-git.git)
```

2. Input your username and password
3. Afterwards, whenever you encounter the popup, all you have to do is close the popup with `esc`.

Comment: Do you think that reinstalling Git will help to deal with this problem? P.S I cannot use your method because I use gh-pages npm package and this package only works with popup login form :(

Comment: @Daler I solved this weird problem with __creating a personal access token__. First of all, create your token in Github - follow [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). And in Windows  [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0), update your Github password to your personal token.